# Tricky big-O calculation

Tags: ds.algorithms, time-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

I have a recursive algorithm in which the time for each step depends on the time for smaller steps. Essentially a structure is built at steps 1, 2, ..., n which must be searched at larger heights:

$$
T(n)=T(n-1)+(1+o(1))\log(T(n-1))
$$

(yes, the larger the time searching the more data is added to the structure!)

It seems 'obvious' that $T(n)\approx n\log n,$ but can this be proved? In particular:
$$
T(n)\stackrel{?}{=}n\log n+o(n\log n)
$$

Better bounds on the error term would be great. I believe the error is $\omega(n).$

Comment: When you have a recurrence that you think you know the correct solution to, it generally works to prove the solution by induction (replacing all big-O type notations with explicit constants, e.g. the 1+o(1) terms in your recurrence and in your proposed solution would be replaced by 1+epsilon or 1+delta for some epsilon and delta that your induction proof will help you quantify). Have you tried that?

Comment: given that what David suggested works very easily (or I haven't had enough coffee yet..) and also is the first thing you learn about bounding recurrences in analysis of algorithms, I think the question is much better fit for CS@SE. voting to close

Comment: @SashoNikolov: I don't think it's as easy as you suggest, especially for the desired error term n log log n. In particular, since the extra work in each term depends on the last (rather than being a function of n), the errors can compound in nonobvious ways. Also I asked a pure-math version of the question (with references to analysis of algorithms removed) at math.se without getting an answer, even after offering a bounty. (Well, I got an informative response, just not one that answered the question.)

Comment: @Charles, could you please give a link to the question on MSE?

Comment: @Kaveh: It should be this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176858/asymptotic-behavior-of-iterative-sequences

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding your question. is there some issue in carrying out david's approach and getting $T(n) \leq n\log n + o(n\log n)$? or are you asking about bounds on lower order terms as well?

Comment: @Charles: In your question, you never said that the desired error term is n log log n.  You should not expect that people can answer a question which you did not state!

Comment: In any case for more precise error control you need to specify $o(1)$.

Comment: @SashoNikolov: If you can prove that (i.e., that for some choices of o(1) the error is not O(n log log n)) I'd accept it as an answer! o(1) is all I know about its behavior; it can act very strangely in fact.